# Omnisharp update v1.23.3 breaks Unity references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

After updating to v1.23.3 omnisharp in VSCode, I'm getting thousands of errors for broken references to commonly used namespaces in Unity.

**What I've tried so far:**

-Regenerating the project files in the External Tools section of preferences

-deleting .vscode folder in project

-reinstalling Omnisharp

-putting "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always" in config file (omnisharp changelog mentions this for Unity)

**Screencap:**[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Rolling back to the previous version appears to be the only [solution](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4110) for now**

I found that you can do this by going to your extensions in VSCode and clicking the gear icon to the bottom right of the Omnisharp extension and then selecting "Install Another Version..." from the context menu.

Comment: Same problem here today. Could something have changed specifically to the project files during this update? I'm currently working in two Unity projects, and one of them seems to have been corrupted by this change, but the other remains untouched, same unity version, same environment, only the projects differ to my knowledge.

Comment: @BagoDev have you tried regenerating your project files in External Tools?  If you haven't, in Unity go to Edit => Preferences => External Tools, and there should be a button that says "Regenerate project files".  If you click this, it should force VSCode to reconfigure when you start it back up.  Usually solves a lot of my issues with broken references and config settings etc.

Comment: yep was one of the first things I tried to no avail.